# How do I move the G+ button down so that it's aligned with everything else

Tags: html, css

I tried reading other answers and just can't get this G+ button to be moved down.
[image]

You can see it in action on https://gimplearn.net

So how can I move the G+ button maybe 8 pixels down?

Current code:

```
<li class="rightside">
  <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://gimplearn.net/" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-size="small" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
  <div  class="g-plusone" data-size="medium" style="display:inline-block;height:23px;vertical-align:bottom;"></div>
  <a href="https://gimp-forum.net" title="Gimp-Forum.net"><img src="https://gimplearn.net/images/gimp-forum.png"></a> | 
  <a href="http://gimpscripts.com" title="GimpScripts.com"><img src="https://gimplearn.net/images/gimpscripts.png"></a> | 
  <a href="http://gimpchat.com" title="GimpChat.com"><img src="https://gimplearn.net/images/gimpchat.png"></a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is quite a strange alignment issue.
You have an `8px` offset...

Try:

```
#___plusone_0{
  transform: translate(0px,8px);  /* arguments are (x,y) */
}
```

If it doesn't work, try with `!important`:

```
#___plusone_0{
  transform: translate(0px,8px) !important;
}
```

This worked, using jQuery, typed straight in the console of your live site:

```
$("#___plusone_0").css({"transform":"translate(0px,8px)"});
```

Comment: do i just add this inside <script> tags?

Comment: Oh inside <STYLE> tags..yeah i did and it and it worked..thanks a million. The first one worked. so I guess i don't need to try the 2nd and the 3rd hehe

Comment: Is there a reference that i could read up on how to use the #___plusone_0...i tried to do the same with the facebook button but not sure how to refer to it

Comment: `#___plusone_0` is the `id` of the element which had to be moved down. You can inspect any webpage HTML markup with the [console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers/77337#77337).